# Jest + Enzyme - test for component visibility to the user

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

Currently we use this to test whether a component has ben rendered:

```
const someComponent = component.find('[data-test="some-component"]').at(0);
expect(someComponent.length).toBe(1);
```

This is fine, but it isn't actually testing that the component is visible to the user - it simply tests that the component exists. How to test that a component both exists and is visible to the user?

Comment: i didn't quite understand what do you mean by existence, if a component is rendered it will be exist for the user unless there is a flag hides the component, in that case you have to toggle the flag in your tests and see if your component is rendered after it or not

Answer (score 7):

Check out https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom which offers a variety of custom DOM matchers for Jest, including `toBeVisible()`.

With it you could write a test like this, which should work:

```js
const someComponent = component.find('[data-test="some-component"]').at(0);
expect(someComponent.getDOMNode()).toBeVisible();
```

**Edit:** though the title of OP's post says "Jest + Enzyme" I should clarify that [`getDomNode()`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/getDOMNode.html) is an Enzyme function, so the above won't work if you're only using Jest. [Here's](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jest.html) the docs page for using Enzyme with Jest.

Comment: TypeError: expect(...).toBeVisible is not a function

Comment: @SimonLong did you import `@testing-library/jest-dom` into your tests setup file? See https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#usage for instructions.

Comment: Here I'm getting TypeError: .getDOMNode is not a function

Comment: @VictorCarvalho that's an Enzyme function (https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/getDOMNode.html) - my answer assumed Enzyme is set up since the original question subject says "Jest + Enzyme", but I'll update my answer to make that clear, for anyone else coming here!

Comment: somehow it's not working for me.   

Received element is not visible (element is not in the document):
      <span class="absolute right-6 bg-white" data-testid="test-selectedCount" />